# Including arguments to make in a Makefile itself

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Is there any way with GNU Make to include arguments to `make` inside of the Makefile itself?  Specifically, if the `--check-symlink-times` argument always applies to a given Makefile is there some way to notate that in the Makefile?  Instead of calling

```
$ make --check-symlink-times
```

It would be nice to just call make by itself and have the Makefile specify some arguments.

```
$ make
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be quite easy. Just put in it a rule at the very top like this:

```
all:
     make --check-symlink-times rest
```

And the rule `rest` somewhere below doing the real task.

Comment: What if it's undesirable to force usage of a limited quantity of "entry" targets.  Your solution works fine if you only ever do `make all`, but what if rest depends upon several targets and I'd like to be able to call those targets independently with the flag added?

Comment: @kgraney: Change `all` to `.DEFAULT all` and `rest` to `$(MAKECMDGOALS)`. And you better add `-f` to specify a separate makefile, or you'll end up in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if that option specifically will work with this mechanism (I believe some don't at least in 3.81) but GNU make does support this concept using `MAKEFLAGS` as seen in [this section](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-setting-options-in-makefiles-444) of the manual.

Answer (score 2):

You can set `MAKEFLAGS` from within the makefile.

```
MAKEFLAGS := --check-symlink-times
```

This will enable checking the ctime of symlinks for this makefile. This seems to work only in more recent versions of GNU make, according to my testing, it works on version `4.1`, but not on version `3.81`.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of is to have a second makefile `makefile.inner` or similar and call one from the other using `-f` or put your source in a subdir and use `-C`, which is often a good idea anyway